# How do SQL implementations internally store duplicate records?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to better understand how SQL works in practice.
Does it store duplicate records as an additional parameter (denoting multiplicity) to a record? Or, do we simply add another duplicate record to the table? Or, some other method? I'm curious as to what most SQL distributions do.

For example, say we had relation R(a, b, c) with integer attributes we could store it internally as follows:

```
Integer-a Integer-b Integer-c Multiplicity
1         2         3         2
```

**Alternatively**

```
Integer-a Integer-b Integer-c
1         2         3
1         2         3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL does not store duplicate records with a multiplicity (and least no database engine that I'm familiar with).

Each record occupies its own space.  Typically, a record is stored on a page, along with other records.  These are the units of I/O that the database uses.

That said, there are some caveats.  For instance, columnar databases store each row independently.  There are compression techniques where adjacent values would be stored with a multiplicity factor.  This is not exactly what you are suggesting, but it is along the same lines.

If you want to understand how databases work, I would suggest that you choose one and study up on it.  MySQL has a pretty simple model (but is complicated by the fact that the storage layer is separate from the processing layer).  Postgres and SQL Server also have reasonable documentation on their page layouts and storage engines.

Comment: I'm surprised it works this way! Especially when there are operations such as bag intersections. In a worst case, O(m) space vs O(1) space.

Comment: @Daniel . . . Don't make the mistake of thinking that any real database is an academically pure implementation of a relational model.  It would be best to say that relational algebra inspired SQL.  In turn, real-world implementations are profoundly affected by more mundane considerations.  Perhaps, relational algebra is the DNA of any given database, but its implementation is shaped more by environmental considerations.

Comment: Note also that nowadays data deduplication frequently occurs on filesystem or lower levels

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SQL engine uses multiplicity. The reason behind that is that in order to use multiplicity (the way you defined it in the question), 2 or more than 2 rows should be same.

Now that won't be the case for engines like Oracle, because oracle implicitly adds id to each row called **row_id**, that will be unique for each row and can use to identify the whole row and its actual/physical storage location.

As far as duplication goes within columns, I guess there won't be any check/comparison of values within column (while insertion of data) unless the column is defined as Primary Key or there is a Unique constraint on column.

Hope it helps!